# Yandex Database права на директорию

Tags: ydb

В Yandex Database NodeJS SDk в примере есть непонятный для меня фрагмент по назначению прав:

https://github.com/ydb-platform/ydb-nodejs-sdk/blob/master/examples/scheme-client/index.ts#L20

```
await driver.schemeClient.modifyPermissions(
        'example-path/subpath',
        [{
            grant: {
                subject: 'tsufiev@staff',
                permissionNames: ['read', 'use']
            }
        }]
    );
```

В документации по поводу управления доступом нашел только раздел: Управление доступом в Yandex Database

https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/ydb/security/start_auth

но там речь ведется про пользователей Yandex облака.

Расскажите пожалуйста - в вышеприведенном примере кому даются права и на что они влияют ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В YDB есть гранулированные права на подобъекты базы, например, на директории и/или таблицы. В данном примере права выдаются объекту в поле subject. Конкретные права описаны в поле permissionNames. @staff -- это имена внутренних инсталляций YDB, в YandexCloud они не поддерживаются.